# Android Expandable ListView - parsed JSON response

Tags: android, json, listview, android-listview

I'm trying to expand my app by offering an Expandable ListView for an existing ListView. The tutorials/answers I've found are often not well documented and don't examine cases where the data is dynamic (in my case a parsed JSON Array response from an API).

I have two data classes: `SearchItem` and `InventoryItem`. I make a call to the API with Volley, and the JSON looks like this:

```
[
  {"product":"foobar", "image_url":"someurl", "inventory_items":
     [
        {"some_attribute":"some_value"},
        {"some_attribute":"some_value"},
        {"some_attribute":"some_value"}
     ]
  },

  {"product.......



  }
]
```

So far I've only parsed out the JSON for `SearchItems` like this:

```
private void parseJsonFeed(JSONArray response) {
        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject searchObj = (JSONObject) response.get(i);

                SearchItem searchItem = new SearchItem();
                searchItem.setId(searchObj.getInt("id"));

                searchItem.setProduct(searchObj.getString("product"));

                searchItem.setItemImg(searchObj.getString("img"));

                searchItem.setId(searchObj.getInt("id"));

                searchItem.setUpc(searchObj.getInt("upc"));

                searchItems.add(searchItem);

            }

            // notify data changes to list adapater
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

How do I now add child `InvetoryItems` to each `SearchItem` in my adapter? While parsing the response I can loop through each `InventoryItem`, but how do I add that as a child element of the corresponding `SearchItem`? Below is my existing extension of BaseAdapter:

```
public class SearchItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {  
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<SearchItem> searchItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public SearchItemAdapter(Activity activity, List<SearchItem> searchItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.searchItems = searchItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return searchItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return searchItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_item, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        TextView product = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product);

        TextView upc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.upc);

        NetworkImageView itemImg = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.itemImg);

        SearchItem searchItem = searchItems.get(position);

        // product info
        product.setText(searchItem.getProduct());

        // item pic
        itemImg.setImageUrl(searchItem.getItemImg(), imageLoader);

        upc.setText(String.valueOf(searchItem.getUpc()));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe read [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) and [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Comment: Thanks, I enjoy his tutorials. Unfortunately the tutorial really only covers a static set of list items. The confusing part for me isn't so much parsing JSON, but more how to parse AND add objects to a ListView as child elements. I sometimes wish he would comment his code a bit more so newbies like me can understand it bit better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First part parsing- You can edit your `SearchItem` code to get and set `List<InventoryItem>` then in your parse method you can iterate through the jsonArray `searchObj.getJsonArray("inventory_item")` create `inventoryItem` object and add it to `inventoryList`, that you can later add to `searchItem`.

Create one separate pojo class for InventoryItem then Edit `SearchItem` class

```
public class SearchItem{
 private List<InventoryItem> inventoryList;
 public void setInventoryList(List<InventoryList> inventoryList)
 {
  this.inventoryList = inventoryList;
 }
 public List<InventoryItem> getInventoryList()
 {
      return this.inventoryList;
 }
 //other object and get/set

}

private void parseJsonFeed(JSONArray response) {
    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject searchObj = (JSONObject) response.get(i);

            SearchItem searchItem = new SearchItem();
            searchItem.setId(searchObj.getInt("id"));

            searchItem.setProduct(searchObj.getString("product"));

            searchItem.setItemImg(searchObj.getString("img"));

            searchItem.setId(searchObj.getInt("id"));

            searchItem.setUpc(searchObj.getInt("upc"));

            if(searchObj.has("inventory_item")
            {
                  JsonArray array = searchObj.getJsonArray("inventory_item");
                  List<InventoryItem> inList = new ArrayList<InventoryItem>();
                  for(int k=0;k<inList.length();k++)
                     {
                       InventoryItem item = new InventoryItem();
                      item.setSomeAttribute(array.get(k).getString("some_attribute"));
                       inList.add(item);
                     }
              searchItem.setInventoryList(inList);
            }

            searchItems.add(searchItem);

        }

        // notify data changes to list adapater
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Second part : Use `ExpandableListAdapter` instead of `BaseAdapter`. return `searchItems.get(groupPosition).getInventoryList().size()` from `getChildrenCount()`

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<SearchItem> list;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<SearchItem> list) {
    this._context = context;
    this.list = list;

}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this.list.get(groupPosition).getInventoryList()
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final InventoryItem item = (InventoryItem) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

    txtListChild.setText(item.getSomeAttribute());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this.list.get(groupPosition).getInventoryList()
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this.list.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this.list.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    SearchItem item = (SearchItem) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(item.getTitle());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. Can you expand on the second part of the problem? That is the crux of the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library http://jackson.codehaus.org/ that parse all the json into object.

To parse your json try this code... response is your JSON.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                        try {

                            List< SearchItem > search = mapper
                                    .readValue(
                                            response,
                                            new TypeReference<List< SearchItem >>() {
                                            });

                            //TODO save your list.

                        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

And your object SearchItem

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

public class SearchItem {

```
public String product;
public String image_url;
public List<Inventario> inventory_items;


public static class Inventario {
    public String Attribute1;
    public String Attribute2;
}
```

}

This can help you to parse your json.

To show, the item you need to use BaseExpandableListAdapter insted of BaseAdapter.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not having a problem parsing the JSON really. The crux of the problem is how to associate parent/child elements and convey to `BaseExpandableListAdapter`.